# Regex Search (Partial Match) isn't Working on Data Table Specific Column

Tags: javascript, regex, datatable

I have a data table where column index 6 represents the posted date and time. I have implemented a search functionality using a calendar input to filter posts from specific dates. However, the search returns all rows without any filtering.

```
var dateColumnIndex = 6;
var specificDateInput = $('#postDate');
var dataTable;
specificDateInput.on('change', applyDateFilter);

function applyDateFilter() {
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#post-table')) {
    dataTable = $('#post-table').DataTable();
    var specificDate = specificDateInput.val().replace(/-/g, "/");
    if (specificDate) {
      dataTable.column(dateColumnIndex).search(specificDate, true, false).draw();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the payload on selecting date:

```
draw: 2
columns[0][data]: checkbox
columns[0][searchable]: false
columns[0][orderable]: false
columns[1][data]: id
columns[2][data]: post_title
columns[3][data]: user.name
columns[4][data]: category
columns[5][data]: tag
columns[6][data]: date
columns[6][search][value]: 2023/07/20
columns[6][search][regex]: true
columns[7][data]: action
columns[7][searchable]: false
columns[7][orderable]: false
order[0][column]: 1
order[0][dir]: desc
start: 0
length: 10
search[value]: 
filter: 1
_: 1688543367938
```

What am I missing in my code that is preventing the filtering of rows based on the selected date?

Comment: _"Here is the payload on selecting date"_ - can you clarify what "payload" means here? What exactly is that data we are looking at there? It's got `search[value]: ` in there, so that looks to me as if your search term was - empty?

Comment: Payload is the data that i am posting to API for fetching the filtered rows. This is not text search rather specific column search.

Comment: Why are you passing `true` as second parameter to the `search` method? You do not have a regular expression here.

Comment: the posted date column is a date time format 2023/07/05 12:07 am but I want to filter only the date. So I need regex here. Isn't it?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search() says it does partial matching already, I don't see why that should behave any different for the search inside just one specific column. Plus, even if you _did_ need a regex - then just setting that flag still doesn't mean that the search term you are passing automatically _was_ a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

To fix these issues, you can modify the applyDateFilter function as follows:

```
    function applyDateFilter() {
       if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#post-table')) {
           dataTable = $('#post-table').DataTable();
           var specificDate = specificDateInput.val(); // Assuming the format is already "yyyy/mm/dd"
         if (specificDate) {
          dataTable.column(dateColumnIndex).search(specificDate, false, false).draw();
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: the posted date column is a date time format `2023/07/05 12:07 am` but I want to filter only date